# raspian - installing ros from source

Tags: ros, raspbian, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I tried to install ROS on a raspbian image (supporting collada and rviz) following the Wiki: http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/groovy%282f%29Installation%282f%29Raspbian%282f%29Source.html

Collada naking and insatllaing worked. According to the tutorial I created a ros_catkin_ws and got the sources from git. The make command is using catkin_make_isolated, which should be in

$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space /opt/ros/groovy

as a source, but it isn't.

The Get command I used (according to the wiki) was:

$ rosinstall_generator --rosdistro groovy desktop > /tmp/groovy_desktop.ri
$ sudo wstool init src -j1 /tmp/groovy_desktop.ri

Does anyone have an idea, why the catkin sources aren't in ./src and how can i git the catkin sources additionally?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190753/raspian---installing-ros-from-source/) by [MartinHummel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4385/martinhummel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably want to pass --deps to the rosinstall_generator.

If that works you can update the documentation here: http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0